# str_replace for br tags not working

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a textarea field on a form that a user submit and it gets saved to a MySQL database.  When I retrieve the value, I'm running nl2br to convert the line breaks to br tags.  Then I'm using str_replace to replace the double br's with p tags.  The issue is nothing is being replaced.  I've looked at this over and over and just can't figure out what could be wrong.

Here's the HTML output:

```
Windows XP Home / Professional
<br />(32 and 64 bit)
<br />
<br />Test Operating System 2
<br />(32 and 64 bit)
<br />
<br />Test Operating System 3
<br />(64 bit)
```

Here's my PHP:

```
$FORMATTED = str_replace("<br /><br />", "</p><p>", $SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS);
```

The output of $FORMATTED looks exactly the same as the HTML output above.  I essentially want to replace all the back to back br tags with the p tag and leave all the single br tags the way they are.

Thank you!!

Comment: you've got `<br />\r\n<br />` or similar in the "html" output. Don't trust what you see in a browser's rendered views. it WILL lie to you. always check `view source` first, and/or capture the text and run it through a hex editor to see EXACTLY what's in the string.

Comment: You should use a regex to replace the continuous `br` tags. `preg_replace('/<br\s*\/>\s*<br\s*\/>', '</p><p>', $SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS);` `\s` replaces any whitespace character

Comment: Thanks @MarcB.  The HTML I posted was from the view source which is where I was getting confused.  So is it as easy as adding \r\n between the br's in my str_replace?  I can try that now....

Comment: no idea. you have to look at exactly what's between the `<br />` tags. e.g. save the original "this isn't working" text somewhere, and use a hex editor to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you are trying to replace `<br /><br />` string, but this string is not in your source. There is `<br />\n<br />` or `<br />\r\n<br />`

Comment: Thanks Jakub!  That did the trick - changed the replace to `<br />\r<br />` and it's working perfectly!